# How do I automatically name tables as they are added to an object?

Tags: r

I have a folder full of CSV files.  I want to pull them all into a single object to make them easier to work with.  I currently have them in what RStudio refers to as "a large list", but if possible I would like to be able to refer to them by their names, rather than by numbers (I'm not likely to know which number is which source file off the top of my head).

Here's a bit of sample code:

```
library(tidyverse)
openfile <- function(filename){
  read_csv(filename) #This function is more complex in reality
}

filenames <- list.files("data/", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
ldf<-lapply(filenames,openfile)
```

The problem is that this seems to return a mess that I can't work with with any ease.  Is there any way to modify things (either the function call, the function itself, or both), so that I can refer to, say,

```
ldf$`table1.csv`
```

or something similar?

Comment: Set the names of the vector you're iterating over, e.g. `names(filenames) <- basename(filenames)`

Comment: `lapply` does not preserve the names from the argument, `sapply` does. `sapply(filename, openfile, simplify = FALSE)` effectively gives you the same `ldf` without explicit naming. (One side-effect is that it will be the entire pathname, as @alistaire's comment bypasses succinctly.)

Comment: Also in one line, you could use `setNames`, like `ldf <- setNames(lapply(filenames,openfile), filenames)`.

Comment: Do the files have a consistent format, or do they have different formats? I agree with other commenters, just set the name after calling lapply. But if they are a similar format, they would also be easy to combine (while preserving names) with rbindlist from the data.table package.

Comment: @be_green - They're different formats.  They're basically these Excel workbooks converted to CSV: http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/4517.02015?OpenDocument